# Excel 2010 VBA only affecting last row in range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba, cells

I have some VBA code written in Excel 2010 to force padding around the rows in a table, but part of the code only affects the last row in the range. Here's the full code:

```
Private Sub FixRowHeight_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim eRow As Excel.Range
Dim padding As Integer
padding = 10
With Worksheets("Issues")
    Set rng = .Range("A2").End(xlDown)
    rng.Select
    .Rows.AutoFit
    For Each eRow In rng.Rows
        eRow.Select
        eRow.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        eRow.RowHeight = eRow.RowHeight + padding
    Next eRow
End With
End Sub
```

Given each time I run it, the entire range autofits the row height, it seems the problem only lies within the for-each loop. Everything enclosed in that loop works just fine for the last row in the range, but that's it. No other row is affected by either of the two actual changes in the loop (vertical alignment & padding).

The entire .xlsm file is a simple one-sheet workbook (deleted the other 2 default sheets). The contents are just a default styled table starting at A1 with column headings and sorting enabled, no functions but adding in the current date.

I have some experience programming, but none in VBA (or any other VB). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you set a breakpoint before the loop and then step through each iteration of the For Each loop -- are the eRows being populated with the right member of rng.Rows for each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem isn't in your loop, it's in your `rng` -

When you `set rng = range("A2").end(xlDown)` you are setting rng to the last cell that is populated down from A2. That is, you're selecting only one cell.

Try -

`Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))`

---

This runs fine -

```
Sub FixRowHeight_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim padding As Integer
padding = 10
With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
    rng.Rows.AutoFit
    For Each Row In rng
        Row.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        Row.RowHeight = Row.RowHeight + padding
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

But, so does this -

```
Sub FixRowHeight_Click()
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.AutoFit
    For Each Row In Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
        Row.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        Row.RowHeight = Row.RowHeight + 10
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Also, just a note, but you don't need to `.select` in your code for `erow` unless the rest of the loop was `selection.verticalalignment` etc.

It's also best to avoid `.select` in general and rather hard-code the ranges, but that's neither here nor there.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Everything I've looked up about adding cell padding above and below rows/cells has said Excel doesn't include that functionality, but I was determined to get it done. I've gotta say, SO really brings out the best code in people. Thanks!